# What non web-oriented Python frameworks exist?

Tags: python, frameworks

I'm looking for a good framework on which to base my applications development.

In PHP I use [Symfony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symfony), in ActionScript [PureMVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PureMVC), they are all MVC frameworks.

I'm looking for **a Python framework being oriented towards general purpose application development**, not web application. I mean, just applications, services, daemons and so on.
Sometimes I have not a real view to implement, just an RPC service. Other times I have to code for a serial port, or implement a command scheduler, or whatever.

What is the best open source software I can think of as a standard base for my needs? Why do you think your suggestion will fulfill my requirements over its competitors?

**EDIT:**

For "general purpose" I mean not being *strongly* bounded to be with or without a GUI, being a daemon or a command-line application, being multiprocess/multithread or not. Being general, giving a good architecture structure, not being a particular tool.

**EDIT 2:**

I'd want to explain that the question is about the *eventual existence* of one or more "frameworks" not being bounded to any particular use case, but being able to give a good and well standardized startup structure/architecture, with some best practices applied, being a guideline, something being able to guide the architecture planning of the application itself, not of their behavior regarding tasks to perform.

I think this question is not so subjective, maybe wrong exposed because of my English, but I suppose it is legal

Comment: What does "general purpose" mean?  GUI?  Non-GUI command line?

Comment: General purpose means exactly "general purpose" :) Not being bounded to be with or without a GUI, being a daemon or a cmd line app, being multiprocess/multithread or not.  Being general, giving a good architecture structure, not being a particular tool.

Comment: Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion.

Comment: @AlberT: Please update your question with additional facts.  Don't comment on your own question when you can update it.

Comment: @Brian Neal I don't have asked anything subjective, if it is not subjective to choose a language over another and so on. I'm asking for real argumentations, not sensations

Comment: Voting to close, in spite of nice answer by Charles Duffy. Subjective/argumentative

Comment: Your question requires extended discussion. Stackoverflow is not a discussion board, as stated in the FAQ.

Comment: I find it funny that the question is tagged "enterprise-development". Obviously normal python development won't do, the asker wants to do enterprise python development.

Comment: Just because most people do not *know* about general frameworks doesn't mean they don't exist. ;-) But yes, of course I thing The Zope Component Architectures features should be a part of the language/standard library, and then his question would be moot. ;)

Comment: @AlberT -- Brian is generally right, in that "best" is subjective, particularly absent context -- it depends by its nature on one's perception of the relative importance of the various costs and benefits involved in the decisionmaking process, and those rankings are context-sensitive by nature; without context, they're highly subjective.

Comment: The question is not particularly subjective, but it is vague and open-ended. But mosts peoples gripe with it is that they think that a generic application framework in Python is pointless, which it isn't. But THEN we start to get subjective and argumentative. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would guess what you're looking for might be the [Enthought Tool Suite](http://code.enthought.com/) (ETS), particularly [Envisage](http://code.enthought.com/projects/envisage/) (extensible plug-in architecture for scientific applications).

Comment: Very interesting. As soon as I will have performed a deeper look into the suite I'm going to accept your answer. +1 for now.

Comment: Quote Albert + 1 for you. I was wondering something more specific than
general answer given until now

Answer (score 9):

For network services needing to handle numerous connections asynchronously, a great many people favor [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).

Outside of that (and web applications), however, there's simply less need for overarching frameworks in Python than with many other languages -- the core language itself is expressive, powerful, and comes with batteries included; why add anything?

Comment: In order to not reinvent the wheel ? :P

Comment: @AlberT, most of the wheels that you might need are already part of the standard library.

Comment: As I have written in the edit of the question, I'm not talking about "tools", but architectures

Comment: @AlberT, your question is way too general to get a better answer than this.  If all you know about your application is that it's an application, there's not much to suggest.

Comment: @Triptych: Actually, there is. The ZCA. See below.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the Zope Component Architecture. It's an architecture to use and reuse components. It's mostly used in web applications because it's used in Zope (as the name implies) but it is in no way web specific.

I wrote a quick intro to it:
http://regebro.wordpress.com/2007/11/16/a-python-component-architecture/

Here is an online book about it: http://www.muthukadan.net/docs/zca.html

And here is a non-online book: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/354076447X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/354076447X)

Answer (score 3):

"not being bounded to be with or without a GUI" doesn't make a lot of sense.

GUI's -- generally -- are quite complex and require a framework.  Folks use [tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), [pyQT](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt), [pyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/), [wxWidgets](http://www.wxpython.org/), etc. to build GUI's.

"daemon or a cmd line app" does not require a framework of any kind.  This is already part of the standard library.

"being multiprocess/multithread or not" is already part of the standard library.

Since, "general" doesn't have much meaning, there are several answers:

- For GUI development, yes, there are many frameworks.  "Best" is subjective.
- For non-GUI development, there are no "additional" frameworks to speak of.
- For "event driven networking", there is [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).
- For "Object-Relational Mapping", there are several.  "Best" is subjective.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having difficulty imagining what a "framework" would be that unifies "with or without a GUI, being a daemon or a cmd line app, being multiprocess/multithread or not". What do you expect such a framework to provide?

Frameworks are built to encapsulate various basic tasks - GUI, or web, or asynchronicity, or whatever - so that, as you say, users don't have to reinvent them. But you're explicitly excluding all the things that make a framework a framework, so I can't see what you're left with.

About the only thing you don't exclude is database access (ORM). If that's all you want, look at sqlalchemy.

Comment: Ok, let help me in choosing a best word than "framework" .. maybe I'm just poor in dict, but my second EDIT should clarify what I mean (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

Python's core language and standard library are an amazing framework by themselves.

Only languages which are deficient in some way need a framework for efficient development of applications (example: JavaScript needs jQuery or [Prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_JavaScript_Framework)).

The general approach with Python is:

1. Check the standard library; it probably has what you need.
2. If there's some large component that isn't in the standard library, there's probably a specific library that help with it.

Answer (score 0):

Python bindings to GObject and GLib provide an application framework not bound to GUI or anything-- however, if it should be bound to a UI, GTK+ comes closer.

GLib provides functions such as an application main loop, events, signals and callbacks. GObject implements the base class for objects with connectable signal slots.

GLib also offers a lot of Filesystem abstraction, including VFS, trash handling, directory monitoring, file metadata.

The python reference is here:

http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygobject/stable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking for exists. Frameworks provide a common frame for similar applications, whereas you are asking for something for all applications. Almost by definition, such a thing can't exist.

Instead, for each application type, unless you find a framework for that specific type of app, you provide the framework yourself and use libraries to provide common functionality shared across applications. Python has many good libraries that come as standard and more can be found at [PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi).